# Why does Google reject my outgoing emails?

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail, spf

I have the following DNS records set up for my mailserver (obfuscated Domain and IPs):

```
mydomain.net.       86400   IN      A      109.83.50.87
mydomain.net.       86400   IN      AAAA   2a00:5080:7:13::1
mydomain.net.       86400   IN      MX     10 mail.mydomain.net.
mydomain.net.       86400   IN      TXT    "v=spf1 mx -all"

mail.mydomain.net.  86400   IN      A       109.83.50.87
mail.mydomain.net.  86400   IN      AAAA    2a00:5080:7:13::1
```

This setup passes any SPF verification tool I could find on the net.

However, if I try to send mail to a gmail account and the server decides to connect via IPv6 to the receiving Google SMTP, the message gets rejected with this bounce:

```
<receiver@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b]
  said: 550-5.7.1 [2a00:5080:7:13::1      16] The sender does not meet basic
  ipv6 550-5.7.1 sending guidelines of authentication and rdns resolution of
  sending 550-5.7.1 ip. Please review 550 5.7.1
  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126for more information.
  o6si5388522eea.99 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

I suspect that something is wrong with my SPF records, but what? What else might be the cause for this?

I haven't tried setting the authorized IPs with 'ip4:xxxx.xxxx...' and 'ip6:xxxx:xxx...' instead of 'mx' yet, but I don't like that way.

Comment: Do you have reverse DNS records set up for v6 address?

Comment: I feel for whoever actually owns `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.net` and perhaps `mydomain.org`. example.com /.net /.org have been reserved for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your ipv6 sending address doesn't have PTR record. According to [google support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126):

> Additional guidelines for IPv6
>
> The sending IP must have a PTR record (i.e., a reverse DNS of the
>   sending IP) and it should match the IP obtained via the forward DNS
>   resolution of the hostname specified in the PTR record. Otherwise,
>   mail will be marked as spam or possibly rejected.

Comment: The PTR record for the IPv6 IPs is correct, but the resulting name in turn only has a A record. I'll try to fix that somehow.

Comment: Solved: it was indeed the forward lookup of the RDNS entry for the mail server that only resolved to an A record, the AAAA record was missing.

Answer (score 1):

dusan.bajic's answer is correct, but could be more helpful.

87.50.83.109.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR    mail.mydomain.net.
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.1.0.0.7.0.0.0.0.8.0.5.0.0.a.2.ip6.arpa. IN PTR mail.mydomain.net.

Those records don't go in the zone file for your domain though.  Given that you're asking this question, I presume it's not you that manages the netblock, and probably the person you need to talk to about the reverse DNS is your hosting provider, or perhaps you can set it up with them through some sort of control panel associated with your account with them.

To test whether it's set up right, run:

```
dig +short -x 2a00:5080:7:13::1
```

and:

```
dig +short -x 109.83.50.87
```

In each case it should return the name of your mail server.

Comment: `dig +trace` is sometimes useful too, to find out where the chain breaks.

Comment: As I wrote in my first post, I obfuscated the addresses. The real one has a working RDNS entry that points to my mailserver's name. But I suspect dusan.bajic's cite is the key here: the mailservers name resolves only to an A record, no AAAA...